# Getting undefined for URL query parameter on directly access to page in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using **Next.js** framework I have a link in the **index.js** file (for client lists page) like:

```
<Link href={{pathname: '/tickets/[id]', query: {id: rowData.id}}}>
  <Button icon='pi pi-eye' />
</Link>
```

And in **[id].js** file (**client-edit** page) I can get query-parameter from `'next/router'` as:

```
const router = useRouter()
const queryParameters = router.query

console.log((queryParameters.id))
```

But the problem is when I try to **directly access** the **client-edit page** I got `queryParameters.id` as `undefined`.

How can I get `id` even when I *directly access to edit page*?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access query params on the first render as client side of next js , you should check if query is ready on client side.
you can gain what you want like this:

```
const router = useRouter()
const queryParameters = router.query

useEffect(() => {
if (router.isReady) {
console.log(queryParameters.id)
}
}, [router.isReady])
```

alternatively for serverSide usage you could use getInitialProps or getServerSideProps to fetch the query parameter

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const { id } = context.query
return props: { id }, // this object will be passed to the component as props
}
```

I hope could solve your problem with this